# Meaning of влезать в/на +mode of transport

Tags: глаголы

Several times, I've seen влезать used in connection with transportation, for getting on a bus, plane, metro, etc. In this usage, does it just mean to get on, or does it have another nuance?

Answer (score 2):

It usually means having some difficulty getting on a bus/train/etc. It doesn't matter what kind of difficulty it is — the bus being overcrowded, too much luggage, broken leg, being tired, you name it.

Comment: Does it also cover cases where the bus is taking off and you just barely catch it?

Comment: It could. Although in this case I would probably use the verb "вскочить". It means (when applied to the bus/train/car/boat etc.) to enter (the bus), demonstrating some dexterity. Again, it doesn't really matter wether this demonstration was needed or not, a young and physically fit person can "вскочить в автобус" instead of entering it in a normal, boring way just because xe is young and fit.

Comment: @CocoPop, probably not. Better to say: вскочил в автобус в последний момент, or  maybe запрыгнул в автобус. But влез is "slower" action, it really means you had some troubles during your action.

Answer (score 1):

влезать (= входить) в автобус - enter the bus

влезать (= залазить) **на** автобус - climb **on** the bus (roof)

Comment: There is no such word залазить, only залезать.